# Book for field and galois theory.

Tags: reference-request, galois-theory, book-recommendation

I studied basic field theory from J.A. Gallian in U.G. and Fraleigh. and a year ago I self studied it from Galois Theory by David A. Cox, and I got pretty good at it. But in last year I was mainly studying groups and non-commutative ring theory, so now I feel like I have lost my sharpness in Field theory and now I want to reread whole Galois field theory. But doing Cox again will feel boring so I was thinking to switch to a  new book. After googling a lot I have shortlisted these small and interesting book-

1) Fields and Galois theory by Howie
2) Galois Theory by Rotman
3) Field and Galois theory by Morandi
4) Galois Theory by Escofier

Which one of these texts is most interesting and insighting? Which one should I buy first, e copies of all of them looked great, but which one I should purchase and read first.

If there are any other suggestions, you are welcome!

Comment: Here is a link to a page on GT as taught by Senior Wrangler Kevin Buzzard: http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~buzzard/maths/teaching/14Aut/M3P11/index.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prefer *Galois Theory* by Ian Stewart, and *Galois Theory of Equations* by David A Cox. Cox is not so bad. Stewart is also good, rather different and interesting.

Comment: for Stewart's book definitely use the unofficial errata list: http://math.illinoisstate.edu/schebol/teaching/407-14-files/Stewart_Corrections.pdf

Comment: Stewart is good, but he intentionally starts with specific, elementary examples.  This may or may not be what the OP wants, since he just wants to review.

Answer (score 6):

If you google "Galois theory pdf" amongst the first four alone are excellent notes by Milne, Baker, and Reid.

These are all excellent teachers and the notes are actually complete texts that are generously made available for free.

Answer (score 3):

The classic [Galois Theory](http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~marin/une_autre_crypto/Livres/Artin%20M.%20Galois%20theory%20%282ed,%20London,%201944%29%2886s%29.pdf) from 1942 by Emil Artin. Not modern but clear.